# VLE/LMS capable of displaying and scoring custom question types?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, educational, user-management

I need an open source VLE (Virtual Learning Environment) or LMS (Learning Management System) that is capable of displaying custom-made question types to students in the form of tests and that can also score the answers.

We will be creating custom questions in a DMS/CMS called Alfresco, they could be placed on a server in the form of HTML pages.

These pages would be displayed in the LMS as tests. For scoring purposes, the answers (or scores of the answers) could then be sent in a JSON format (possibly even XML) back to the LMS which adds these scores in the system.

I've looked at Moodle but it doesn't seem to be able to add custom questions.

**Requirements**

- should be open source
- user management (students & teachers)
- custom content should be easily integrated into the system
- scoring that content is vital

**Preferably**

- not too many unnecessary features as user management and scoring are the most important requirements

Comment: you can look for a moodle plugin that does what you want or create one or hire someone to do it for you https://moodle.org/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

## [Course Builder](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/)

> Course Builder is an Open Source (Apache 2.0), online education
>   platform. Use it to create your online course whether it's for an
>   entire university offering, professional training, or a corporate
>   product. Course Builder:
>
> - has a [rich feature set](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/wiki/FeatureList)
> - massively scales because it runs on Google infrastructure
> - has a free tier
> - supports multiple courses on the same instance (multitenancy)
> - support for Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager
> - requires no programming to create or run your course
> - is relatively quick to get up and running

## Notes

Course builder has its own way to [create questions](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/wiki/CreateQuestions). It

> ... separates the writing of questions with activities and
>   assessments. This facilitates question management in that you can see
>   a list of all questions that you will ask for a course, reuse
>   questions, separate the responsibilities of writing informational
>   content versus question content, etc.

### Requirements fulfillment

> - should be open source

Yes.

---

> - user management (students & teachers)

Maybe. Need clarification of expectations.

> > **Do my students need a Google account to register for a course made with Course Builder?**
> >     Yes, if students want to register for a course made with Course
> >     Builder, they will need a Google account. However, if you turn
> >     browsing on for your course through course settings, students can take
> >     your course without ever registering.

---

> - custom content should be easily integrated into the system

Yes.

---

> - scoring that content is vital

Maybe. Need clarification of expectations.

---

**References**
[Google | Open online education](https://www.google.com/edu/openonline/)